# What to use for scheduling a .NET Application to run daily?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, scheduled-tasks

I have a .NET 4 console application, that when run makes data requests using ERPConnect using an R3Connection to SAP and fetches some mapping data from a SQL Server database before loading transformed data into that same SQL Server database.

I have been asked to make this run on a daily schedule.

Does anyone have recommendations on how this should be done?

My initial thoughts would be:
A .bat file and Windows Task Scheduler
OR
Windows Powershell

Does anyone have any suggestions or reasons why you would pick one over the other?

Comment: Task Scheduler is pretty much the standard way of doing that..

Comment: Task Scheduler is the right way to do it. On a server that is online 24/7 - **not** your desktop!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), and schedule the task.  This is a simple, easily reconfigurable approach, and can be configured to run your console application directly (with no need for the batch file).

The advantage here is that you can change the schedule, such as time of day or frequency at any time, merely by configuring the system's schedule.

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest doing it using Windows Task Scheduler and the batch file.  A question would be , though, do you actually need the batch file?  I have plenty of apps that are called from the  WTS and it can call applications directly.  I'd suggest altering your console app so you can eliminate the need for a batch file.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, yes your right if I don't need it I don't want it. Any basic pitfalls with doing this?

Comment: None other than you must have the computer on and the service running.. it won't catch up on missed tasks.

Answer (score 1):

You can set up a scheduled job from PowerShell fairly simply:

```
Register-ScheduledJob -FilePath \\svr\share\foo.ps1 -Trigger @{Frequency=Daily;At="9:00PM"} -ScheduledJobOption @{WakeToRun}
```

This does require PowerShell v3.  Behind the scenes it is using the task scheduler.  There is also a `Register-ScheduledTask` cmdlet for register tasks that don't correspond to running PowerShell scripts.

Whether you do this manually using the task scheduler UI or automate with a script depends on whether this is a one time setup (go manual) or you will need to repeat the task setup either on one machine or on multiple machines (automate it).

Answer (score 0):

For as simple as what you are doing Windows Task Scheduler would work just fine.  Something we have done though especially since your dealing with an ERP system like SAP, is I made a windows service that hits a table and inside that table is a list of assemblies and classnames that I wanna kick off based of a interval and next run dateTime. Using reflection I call the class in the assembly I need to run based off the nextrun date time compared to current date time.  Also each class would accept a nameValueCollection, so I could create XML column for each class to pass down configuration settings to each class on the fly.  All I gotta do is update that column and next run time new settings are in place without the service having to be stopped or restarted.  Granted you could have your console app pull in a config file each time it runs and do basically the same thing (I would highly suggest you do that if you use the windows scheduled task manager).  This makes it nice is PRD goes down and you need to point an app quickly to a QAS or dev system, or to maintain usernames and passwords(I would encrypt if your going to do that). Also having that data driven back end can allow you to build a front end if you need a business analyst to have some control over that particular task. It might sound like a lot of work but its not really.

Also a note:  I am sure that you're not setting this up on XP likely but if you are keep in mind I have seen multiple times that WTS cryptoservice (not sure cryptoservice is 100% correct, but its something along those lines. ) gets corrupted and scheduled tasks fail and it can be a mess.  We have RFC's running on machines for SAP to pick up files and a scheduled task that made sure they were running and sometimes those things would fail and RFC's would not get restarted and cause all kinds of issues.